# Linq - Group, Sum and Max

Tags: c#, linq

I've been stuck with this problem for a few days now.

How do I group by PartCode, take the Max/Min or First value of the Description (items with the same partcode may have a different description), and then sum of the other fields. What I currently have is shown below:

```
var lengths =
                from q in
                    (from p in partList
                     select new { p.PartCode, p.Description, p.Quantity, p.TotalMeter, p.PurchaseLength })
                group q by new { q.PartCode, q.Description, q.Quantity, q.TotalMeter, q.PurchaseLength } into g
                orderby g.Key.PartCode
                select new
                {
                    PartCode = g.Max(p => p.PartCode),
                    Description = g.Max(p => p.Description),
                    Quantity = g.Sum(p => p.Quantity),
                    TotalMeter = g.Sum(p => p.TotalMeter),
                    PurchaseLength = g.Sum(p => p.PurchaseLength)
                };
```

Comment: I think the main thing that is missing here is saving a reference to the group in the last select clause (something like `Group = g`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two main problems here:

The first is that you say you want to group by PartCode, but instead you're grouping by a combination of everything.

Another possible problem is that you're using `Max()` on what I can only assume to be collections of strings. This won't fail, but it will select the value that is last in alphabetical order (is that what you want?).

Try this:

```
var lengths =
    from q in
        (from p in partList
        select new { p.PartCode, p.Description, p.Quantity, 
                     p.TotalMeter, p.PurchaseLength })
    group q by q.PartCode into g
    orderby g.Key
    select new
    {
        PartCode = g.First().PartCode,
        Description = g.First().Description,
        Quantity = g.Sum(p => p.Quantity),
        TotalMeter = g.Sum(p => p.TotalMeter),
        PurchaseLength = g.Sum(p => p.PurchaseLength)
    };
```

If that doesn't solve your issue *please tell us what your issue is*.

Comment: P1 - I think that was were I gave it and tried everything. P2 - It doesn't matter regarding the description, they were all pretty similar anyway.  Thanks a bunch!